# Flutter: Automatically change the data in firebase cloud database after specific time period

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose i created a document in cloud firestore and i want that data to be changed after 5 mins of data creation.
How can i do that job in dart(framework:flutter).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to update your Firestore document at a specific time frequency, you may consider [scheduled Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). This method of updating documents creates a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic and Cloud Scheduler to trigger events on that topic, which ensures that your function runs on the desired schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer for update data after specific time.

```
Timer _timer;
int _start = 10;

void startTimer() {
  const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  _timer = new Timer.periodic(
    oneSec,
    (Timer timer) => setState(
      () {
        if (your logic) {
          //Your code
        } else {
         //Your code
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: What if the user exists from that page or kills the app from background.